# Count number of polygons of a mesh

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, mesh, polygons, flare3d

I need to find the number of polygons of a mesh. Unfortunately, the engine I use (Flare3D) doesn't seem to have such a property. In fact, each Mesh is simply consisted of **Surfaces** which have the [badly documented following properties](http://www.flare3d.com/docs/flare/core/Surface3D.html):

```
indexVector
numTriangles (=-1?)
polys (=null?)
sizePerVertex
vertexVector
```

I tried some combinations, e.g.

```
    for each (var mesh:Mesh3D in meshes) {
        for each (var surface:Surface3D in mesh.surfaces) {
            tris += surface.vertexVector.length;
        }
    }
    trace("tris",tris,tris/24);
```

and `tris/24` seems to give the correct number of triangles but **NOT** for every model I tested...

**EDIT:**

numTriangles seems to be filled with the correct number of triangles after rendering is performed, but:

- It's render-based, I would like to find out without interfering with any rendering at all
- It reports number of triangles; the mesh may be consisted of quads and/or triangles!

Comment: Maybe property polys holds list of surface polygons. Polygon has number_of_vertices-2 triangles.

Comment: @Ante Unfortunately polys vector is always null...